# How to create FCM registration token using Firebase Admin sdk

Tags: firebase, go, firebase-cloud-messaging, web-push

How to create FCM registration token on Go using Firebase Admin sdk
I can create custom token but I need to create FCM registration token so that I can sent web push notification to my web app

Comment: The language is simply called "Go". Not "Golang", not "Go-lang".  Just "Go".

Comment: To my knowledge, there's no way to geneate it by SDK.

Comment: @p1gd0g , it means I have to create it by javascript ?? right??

Comment: @PrinkalKumar By "front". The key is, how could fcm server "knows" your device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading Go-Admin-SDK documantion,Currently(3 Feb 2021) there is no such option to create Registration token from Go. Alternatively we can use javascript FCM library to do so